# Kotlin non-null assertion on null

Tags: android, android-studio, null, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

As Kotlin have the non-null assertion, I found some funny stuff...

```
val myvar: String = null!!
```

It will crash.

But the point is, it doesn't check at compile time.

The app will crash at runtime.

Shouldn't it throw compile time error?

Comment: FYI: IntelliJ IDEA does mark `val myvar: String =` with a warning: "Unreachable code".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`!!` is evaluated at runtime, it's just an operator.

The expression `(x!!)`

- throws a `KotlinNullPointerException` if `x == null`,
- otherwise, it returns `x` cast to the corresponding non-nullable type (for example, it returns it as a `String` when called on a variable with type `String?`).

This, of course, makes `null!!` shorthand for `throw KotlinNullPointerException()`.

---

If it helps, you can think of `!!` as doing the same as a function like this does:

```
fun <T> T?.toNonNullable() : T {
    if(this == null) {
        throw KotlinNullPointerException()
    }
    return this as T // this would actually get smart cast, but this 
                     // explicit cast demonstrates the point better
}
```

So doing `x!!` would give you the same result as `x.toNonNullable()`.